# Google Plus sharing not working in mobile Safari

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus, social-media

I was implemented Google sharing feature one of my app and it was working fine. But suddenly it stopped working giving below error on Safari. It was sharing feature not using native dialog box in G+.

[image]

Comment: check your gmail account your post share or not?

Comment: i think your post share on google plus

Comment: NO it wasn't posted on G+ and not redirecting back to the application.

Comment: This is not working in Google plus sample application as well. I don't know Im stuck in here.

Comment: yes but text share on G+